# Как рисовать графики в Java?

Tags: awt, java, swing

Как рисовать графики в Java?

Comment: Есть данные типа double: х=1, x=2...  и у=0.000111, y=0.002133...

Comment: Подойдёт ли метод: drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints) из класса Graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пару недель назад сам столкнулся с этой проблемой, попалась под руку эта библиотека.

http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp

Я остался доволен, разбираться с ней недолго, т.к много примеров есть прям там на сайте + документация, но это если ты совсем решишь глубоко разобраться.

Comment: alex91, спасибо! Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 2):

Не до конца понятно, что тебе рисовать... Если у тебя простые фигуры то воспользуйся Java 2D Graphics. А если тебе конкретно различные графики рисовать, то есть замечательная либа [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Пример программы выводящей графики математичесских функций, принцип прост - просчитываете одну точку, а вторая следует ей на шаг назад. Между этими точками рисуются линии [Java, Графики функций](http://ivarious.com/index.php?onecategory=&id=54)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static final int SCALE = 32; // шкала пискселей, размер клетки
public static final int WIDTH = 20; // ширина
public static final int HEIGHT = 20;// высота

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  


    g.setColor(Color.black);
    for (int x = 0; x <= WIDTH * SCALE; x += SCALE) {
        g.drawLine(x, 0, x, HEIGHT * SCALE);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y <= HEIGHT * SCALE; y += SCALE) {
        g.drawLine(0, y, WIDTH * SCALE, y);
    }


}
```

Если я правильно понял, нужно сформировать визуал решетки ?

Comment: Нет, вопрос был о построении графиков

Comment: Теоретически, с помощью graphics.drawline можно расчертить нужное поле и запустит в нем график с логикой по по типу двухмерного массива который будет уходить по оси Х в право, а по оси Y будет изменятся вверх или в низ в зависимости от написаной логики.